# Reverse proxy with request dispatch (to Rstudio server)

Tags: apache, gwt, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, rstudio-server

I have a multi-tier application of three layers lets say public, business and workspace (all running apache). 
Client requests hits the public servers, requests are processed and dispatched on to business servers that does 'things' and response is returned back to public server which then processes the response and pass it on to the client. 
I have a scenario wherein I want a request say /rstudio coming to the public server dispatched onto the business which intern reverse proxy to workspace server. There are two catch here:

1. the workspace server varies per request
2. application running on workspace server (Rstudio) uses GWT and references resources (static resources js, css etc and RPC coms) on the root url. All the in-application redirection also happens on the domain.

From the business server, I have setup reverse proxy to Rstudio server from my application server.

```
<Proxy *>
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        /rstudio/ http://business_server/
ProxyPassReverse /rstudio/ http://business_server/
RedirectMatch permanent ^/rstudio$ /rstudio/
```

and this work fine (ref. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-with-a-Proxy). To handle dynamic workspace server, I could the following but ProxyPassReverse does not support expression in value and this no joy with this approach.

```
ProxyPassMatch    ^/rstudio/(.*)$ http://$1
ProxyPassReverse  ^/rstudio/(.*)$ http://$1
RedirectMatch permanent ^/rstudio$ /rstudio/
```

I have tried the same with mod_rewrite rule (following) but without ProxyPassReverse and due to domain redirection on the GWT Rstudio, this does not work. Adding ProxyPassReverse would fix the problem but I am caught up with no expression on value part to deal with dynamic workspace server issue.

```
RewriteRule "^/rstudio/(.*)" "http://$1" [P]
```

Following is the third approach to solve this problem using LocationMatch and mod_headers:

```
   <LocationMatch ^/rstudio/(.+)>
    ProxyPassMatch http://$1
    Header edit Location ^http:// "http://%{SERVER_NAME}e/rstudio/"
   </LocationMatch>
```

But this is no joy too because value on header directive is not evaluated against environment variable (and only back-references work here). Althought I can get the reverse proxy thing working if I had code the business_server, which is :

```
   <LocationMatch ^/rstudio/(.+)>
     ProxyPassMatch http://$1
     Header edit Location ^http:// "http://private_server/rstudio/"
   </LocationMatch>
```

***Question 1:*** I was wondering if there are any better way to solve this problem without hardcoding the server DNS in apache conf?

***Question 2:*** With the hard coded server DNS the reverse proxy works for me (patchy but works) but I am hit with GWT issue of resource references on root and the request dispatch is not fully working. I get to the signin page but resources are not found.

I was wondering if there is any better way to handle that?

Following is the example log from browser:

```
Navigated to https://public_server/rstudio
rworkspaces:43 GET https://public_server/rstudio.css 
rworkspaces:108 GET https://public_server/js/encrypt.min.js 
rworkspaces:167 GET https://public_server/images/rstudio.png 404 (Not Found)
rworkspaces:218 GET https://public_server/images/buttonLeft.png 404 (Not Found)
rworkspaces:218 GET https://public_server/images/buttonTile.png 404 (Not Found)
rworkspaces:218 GET https://public_server/images/buttonRight.png 404 (Not Found)
```